# How many arrangements are there of the word “PERMUTATIONS” so that no three vowels come together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

I did this-

Total Arrangements without any constraint - Total arrangements when 3 Vowels together = Total arrangements when no 3 vowels are together.

$\frac{12!}{2} - (\frac{10!}{2} \cdot {}_5C_3 \cdot 3\cdot2) = 130636800$.

But the answer seems wrong. What am I doing wrong? I need help.

Comment: Consider the ways when $4$ vowels are together, When you counted for the "bad cases" such arrangements were counted twice. Why? Because lets say the vowels are $A,E,I,O......$, then you count $A,E,I$ as well as $E,I,O$. Can you use a similar method to find how much you overcounted when $5$ vowels were together?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2104366/in-how-many-arrangements-of-the-letters-of-the-word-intermediate-2-vowels-never?rq=1)